# Memcmp seems to be giving me an incorrect return value

Tags: c++, c, memory, gdb

I have two unsigned char arrays of the same size and an if statement that checks to see if they're equal:

```
    #define BUFFER_SIZE 10000

    unsigned char origChar[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char otherChar[BUFFER_SIZE];

    //Yes, I know this is unnecessary

    memset(origChar,'\0',BUFFER_SIZE);
    memset(otherChar,'\0',BUFFER_SIZE);

    . . .
    if(memcmp(origChar,otherChar,offset))
    {
        . . .
    }
```

When I examine the two arrays in gdb, I get the following:

```
(gdb) p origChar
$1 = '\000' <repeats 9999 times>
(gdb) p otherChar
$2 = '\000' <repeats 9999 times>...
(gdb) p memcmp(otherChar,origChar,offset)
$3 = 1
```

However, if I decrement `offset` by 1, I get the following:

```
(gdb) p memcmp(otherChar,origChar,offset-1)
$4 = 0
(gdb) p offset
$5 = 10000
```

It doesn't really make any sense to me. GDB basically says they're completely equal, so why would decrementing `offset` by one change things?

Comment: Why is `offset` different to `BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: The value of `offset` is meant to change, but in this case, `BUFFER_SIZE` and `offset` have an equivalent value of 10000.

Comment: What is the value of `offset`?  What is the value of `BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: I added the definition of `BUFFER_SIZE` and `offset` was already in the post

Comment: @Sky The question now is this -- what does your program *really* do?  Is it just something with gdb, or does your program actually return wrong results?

Comment: No issue here:  http://ideone.com/38MTc6

Comment: I think I've got it now. The `p origChar` and `p otherChar` statements made me think that the two arrays were equal. `p otherChar[9999]` and `p origChar` showed me how wrong I really was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... Reading your dump, I can tell you that `origChar` and `otherChar` are both `'\0'*9999` ; while you're trying to compare the first 10000 bytes when using offset. So there is probably a difference in the 10000'th byte.

Using `offset-1`, you're comparing the first 9999 bytes, hence the equality.

The "bug" thus comes from something you do in your first "`. . .`" that modifies the 10000'th value.

Comment: Yes, it seems you're completely right. I did `p otherChar[9999]` and `p origChar` and got completely different results. I had just thought that they were equal because of what GDB told me.